# Parse query in ViewDidLoad for UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm trying to adapt the use of a UICollectionViewController I'm populating with an Array of local images to get the images from Parse.

So far it's pretty straightforward. My NSArray is filled with the same local image many times:

testImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", @"thumbnail.jpg", nil];

On the collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: I do set up my cell (from Storyboard):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Set up cell identifier that matches the Storyboard cell name
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";    
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell to show photo thumbnail
    UIImageView *testImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    testImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[testImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

This is working and looks like this:

[image: UICollectionViewController with array of local images]

What I'm trying to do is to replace the locally created array from pictures that I get out of my Photo Class in Parse.

I'm trying to do this on the viewDidLoad method:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];

PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:user];
[query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
[query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];


[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d photos.", objects.count);
        testImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:objects];
        NSLog(@"# Images: %d", [testImages count]);

        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {                
            NSLog(@"Object Name: %@", object.objectId);
        }


    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

The thing is that I'm getting an empty array every time. I'm guessing that since this is getting executed on the block in the background once the collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection: asks for the count of elements on the "testImages" array I always get 0 elements.

When the UICollectionViewController wants to use the information from the array to fill in the cells there's nothing there.

I don't know if I'm placing my code in the wrong place or if I'm using the wrong query.

Can you get my error here?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the completion block, calling the reloadData method on your collectionView will populate the cells. I'm not sure this is the answer you are looking for, but it will work

Comment: Hi @gg13, this worked out thanks but it seems a bit weird. I'm printing the number of retrieved objects (with NSLog) and I first get a 0, then after the reloadData I get the proper amount. Is this a regular way of working with UICollectionViewController? It seems strange although I must confess I'm no expert yet.

Comment: What's happening is that when you are first printing out the number of retrieved objects, Parse has not completed the query for the objects, so it returns 0. Along the same lines, the collection view is trying to set itself up with an empty array, which is why you get nothing. Then, because you call reloadData in the completion block, the query has been completed so you have your objects, and the collection view can populate itself. It's really nothing different than UITableView's, as they would be unable to populate itself without any objects as well.

Answer (score 4):

finally I got something working. @gg13's feedback has been key to solve the empty array problem.

I'll leave the solution here just in case it helps anyone else some other time.

I put my query on a new method:

```
- (void)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:user];
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    [query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d photos.", objects.count);

            [self.collectionView reloadData];

            gridImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:objects.count];

            // Do something with the found objects
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
                [thumbnail getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        // Now that the data is fetched, update the cell's image property with thumbnail

                        NSLog(@"Fetching image..");

                        [gridImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];

                        NSLog(@"Size of the gridImages array: %d", [gridImages count]);

                    } else {
                        // Log details of the failure
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                    }
                }];
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

That I'm calling on viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self queryForTable];
}
```

Then I changed my collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: method to this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Set up cell identifier that matches the Storyboard cell name
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";    
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell to show photo thumbnail
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    //NSLog(@"testImages: %@", [testImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"];

    imageView.image = [gridImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

And so far it's working. The app is getting the images from Parse and it looks like this:

[image: UICollectionViewController with Parse images]

I still have to test a few things and specially the scenario with huge amount of images (including a progress indicator or something) but at least to get this already is a good thing.

I'm sure Parse will make their own UICollectionViewController sooner or later as they did with the UITableViewController and things will improve even more.

As said before, thanks for the feedback, I'm leaving this here just in case someone else comes into the same problem and of course open to feedback and suggestions.

Cheers,